# AMP page not showing on Mobile devices,even it is there

Tags: canonical-link, amp-html, rel

I have already created AMP pages for mobile users of my website.The problem is" when I try to access my website from mobile,it shows web version" and also "If I try to access AMP page from desktop and laptop,it only shows AMP page and does not send my request to NON-Amp page.

1.AMP page fully qualified and without any errors
2.I used

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.moztech.in/demo/ampindex.html">
```

in Non amp version,

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.moztech.in/demo/index.html">
```

in AMP version.

If possible review my code and help me.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of AMP. It doesn't do any redirection at all so if you put in the AMP URL into your desktop browser, then you will be going to the AMP page. If you want it to have redirection then you would have to implement it on your own on your server. **AMP will not handle any of your redirection, just think of it as a subset of HTML and nothing more.**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've set everything up correctly. However, AMP will not do any automatic re-direction.

AMP is designed so that applications may choose to serve the AMP page instead of the standard canonical page. For example,

- Google's mobile search will usually display the AMP version of a page instead of the canonical version when available.
- Messaging apps may choose to display the AMP version of a page when you receive a link from a friend.
- Social networks may display the AMP version of a page within their app when you click on a shared link from within the app.

Because the `link` tag on your canonical page provides information about where to find the AMP version, it is possible for apps to automatically select the faster and more mobile-friendly mobile experience that AMP delivers. However, this decision is made at the application level, and is not handled by the AMP itself.

Comment: So according to above, does this mean that if I have desktop site xyz.com and its relative amp site as xyz-amp.html, then when <link> ref is added for both amp and non-amp site, will the mobile google search show amp version and desktop google search show the non-amp version?

Comment: Generally, yes. However note that Google decides whether to display AMP page or canonical page, and it can happen at the page level. Also, Google is not the only vendor who will display AMP if it's available. Bing, Twitter, Pinterest, and others can detect AMP and may display it instead of canonical when AMP is available.